# SQL - Get a subset based on Datetime using OVER clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query against the following dataset that will separate the last updated records based on a unique set of fields..

Assume for the following example the the unique set of fields is val1 + val2 + val3.

I tried using window functions to achieve this, but there seems to be another level of complexity for this example.

```
  --DROP TABLE #demo;

  -- assume there is a unique key on val1 + val2 + val3
  CREATE TABLE #demo
  (
      id int NOT NULL,
    val1 varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    val2 varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    val3 varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      last_updated DATETIME NOT NULL,
    active bit not null
  );

  INSERT INTO #demo VALUES
  (0,'a','b','c', '20150817', 0),
  (1,'a','b','c', '20150817', 0),
  (2,'a','b','c', '20150817', 0),
  (3,'a','b','c', '20150815', 0),
  (4,'a','b','c', '20150815', 0),
  (5,'d','e','f', '20150701', 0),
  (6,'d','e','f', '20150630', 0),
  (7,'d','e','f', '20150630', 0),
  (8,'d','e','f', '20150630', 0)

  -- using unique key columns, trying to get only those with the most recent date
  SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY val1, val2, val3 ORDER BY last_updated DESC)   AS RowNum 
  FROM #demo
```

I am hoping to return only the highlighted records below (id: 0,1,2,5) with the query.[image: result]

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1  very well presented question with test data , desired output and your attempt, I wish everyone did that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
      SELECT *
           , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY val1, val2, val3 
                                            ORDER BY last_updated DESC)   AS RowNum 
      FROM #demo
      )t 
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.* from
demo d  join
(
 SELECT val1,val2,val3 ,
 max(last_updated) as mx
 FROM demo
 group by val1,val2,val3) x 
on x.val1 = d.val1 and x.val2 = d.val2 and x.val3 = d.val3
and x.mx = d.last_updated
```

This is one more approach.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a82b/12)